# How to log flag changes to files on ext4 and xfs filesystems?

Tags: ext4, xfs, audit

I was wondering how to log flag changes in a file, e.g. `chattr +a somefile`.

I realized that timestamps shown by `stat somefile` are not useful to audit flag changes: when the file is appended, it overrides the last time a flag was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auditd` was created exactly for that. `inotify/fsnotify` require a ton of code to be useful and they are generally not used for this purpose.

There are plenty of manuals on the net, e.g.

- https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-audit-file-access-on-linux/
- https://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-monitor-file-access-on-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [Inotify](https://medium.com/100-days-of-linux/an-introduction-to-file-system-monitoring-tools-afd99164ce66) It's just for some directories, not for the all filesystem.
Humm.... I found the [fsnotify](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=90586523eb4b349806887c62ee70685a49415124).

Comment: There's a long time I don't play with inotify. The fanotify seems interesting, too. But, I was thinking if there is some sort OS mechanism that already keep log of the timestamp of the last chattr change on a file. Or maybe an audit package to do that...